# Why does this work? Recursive str_length function in c++

Tags: c++, recursion, arguments, c-strings

This is a recursive function to find the length of a cstring in c++. I am happy that I found an answer to the project problem but I have no idea why it works. The line in question is this one: **"return (str_length(s + 1) + 1);"** I have no understanding why the s+1 as an argument works. Any clarification would be lovely.

**EDIT**
The course has not covered pointers.

```
int str_length(char s[])
{
    if (s[0] == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return (str_length(s + 1) + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: `s + 1` moves the pointer by one character.

Comment: `int str_length(char s[])` is actually `int str_length(char* s)`. so you have pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @wally So it calls s[0+1] then s[1+1] and so on? Thank you for the answer.

Comment: If the course hasn't covered pointers yet, then you cannot be able to understand this program based on what you learned in the course until now. You should not be using this example code in that case. (Try to write your own as instructed!) Note however that `char s[]` *is* a pointer disguised with array syntax. You can use it as if it was an array and write an iterative solution (rather than recursive one as in the shown code), but that is not technically correct and IMHO pointers should be taught before giving such an assignment.

Comment: Aside from that you should be taught how to use `std::string`, not C-style null-terminated strings, if you are supposed to learn C++ rather than C.

Comment: @uneven_mark I did come up with this on my own. I was told to write a recursive function and wrote something that stuck and then decided to find out why it worked. I didn't write the curriculum I am just taking the course.

Comment: @user9549389 Without knowing about pointers I don't know how one would come up with this code. One can treat `s` as an array and pass around a second argument containing the current index to write a recursive function, not relying on knowledge of pointers (with the caveat I mentioned earlier), if it really has to be recursive.

Comment: I spent quite a while trying to figure out how to start from a different point before trying this. I literally wrote something that I expected to break and it worked. It makes no intuitive sense so I figured I would ask why it worked. Now I know.

Answer (score 0):

`char s[]` when used in a function parameter is really `char* s`, i.e. a pointer to `char`, not an array of `char`. This is a confusing notation, which is why I suggest not using it.

What is passed to the function is a pointer to the first element of an array of `char` and the function's job is to find the first character in that array that has the value `'\0'` and return that elements position in the array.

When you write `s + 1` you are forming a pointer pointing to the array element after the one that `s` points to. You then pass this to the recursive call to `str_length`.

Because the recursive call now takes a pointer pointing to the second element of the original `char` array containing the C-style string, it will return the length of the original string minus one. Adding one to the result in `(str_length(s + 1) + 1)` will return the actual string's length.